Installing a Pre-hung Interior Door
I have a pre-hung interior door whose frame is approx 2” wider than the rough-in opening. Cut it to match the rough-in opening?

Your question isn't clear. You seem to be asking us to make a judgement call for you with little context. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise to be more specific.

Interior doors are not known to have much wood to cut, maybe 1/4 or 1/2 inch per side.  Your best bet is exchanging the door for one that fits.

...buy the right sized door? Adjust the rough opening to fit the door you have? the options are endless, but 10 pounds of stuff in a 5 lb bag tends not to fit, and spill stuff all over the floor...

Definity sounds like you have a door too big.  If it is a 32 go to a 30 if a 30 go to a 28, etc then the door should fit the rough opening.

We are all assuming you mean a door that will not fit in an opening.  Is this right or you mean a door frame that sticks out into the room by two inches/depth of the frame compared to depth/thickness of the wall.

Get a smaller door.
